# How to install Lua GUI in ZBS IDE

Tags: lua, installation, zerobrane

I am completely new to programming in Lua outside a sandbox.

I have found a library called Lua GUI that I'd like to use (https://github.com/williamwilling/luagui/). I have still not understood how to quite install the library, and how I even go about using it.

That's part 1 of my question; How can I install Lua GUI(or an library for that matter), and then how do I go about actually using it? By that I mean, is it as simple as writing a program that starts with "require "gui"" and then running it, or is there more to it?

Part 2 of my question is then how do I go about installing it as a package for ZeroBrane Studio IDE, I have no idea at all what the readme file is instructing me to do so I would be grateful if someone could clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the contents of the `src` folder in the `luagui` project to your project directory you should be able to call:

```
local gui = require("gui")
```

in your main Lua file and use it that way.